# Magento 1.9 multiple add to cart button

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I want to show two `Add To Cart` button in `view.phtml` page. those buttons are following,

1. Add To Cart
2. Insta Buy

`Add To Cart` button working with normal functionality, It works fine.

But When user click `Insta Buy` directly redirect to `checkout/onepage`. I tried some code but it goes to `checkout/cart` page. That code is following

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Insta Buy') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Insta Buy') ?></span></span></button>
```

> I want to redirect to `checkout/onepage` page. How can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the code bellow in: `app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtml`

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Insta Buy') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setcheckoutLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage') ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Insta Buy') ?></span></span></button>
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function setcheckoutLocation(location,checkout)
     {
         jQuery.ajax({
                type:"GET",
                url:location,
                success:function(data){
                     window.location.href = checkout;
                }
          });
     }
 </script>
```

Comment: Oh Prince thanks for your code it working

Comment: But quantity not increasing

Comment: this solution will simply redirect to checkout page, without incrementing the qty

Comment: @Ramesh S yes, he gets a product without qty, you need a little update for this

Comment: @Prince: Sorry for my wrong question. How can i increase  qty

Comment: @ManashviBirla: Thanks for your command bro :)

Comment: @Prince: Please check my code now i can incrementing the quntity 
 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194261/magento-1-9-multiple-add-to-cart-button/194350#194350

Comment: @ManashviBirla: Bro Please check my code now i can incrementing the quntity 
 https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/194261/magento-1-9-multiple-add-to-cart-button/194350#194350

Answer (score 2):

This code for pass product data with quantity

```
app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/template/catalog/product/view.phtml
```

Form values pass here

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post"  id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
```

.
    `app/design/frontend/{yourpackage}/{yourtheme}/template/catalog/product/view/addtocart.phtm`

Code

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Insta Buy') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setcheckoutLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage') ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Insta Buy') ?></span></span></button>
```

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                 function setcheckoutLocation(location,checkout)
                 {
                    var data = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();
                    jQuery('#preloader .loader').fadeIn(300);
                     jQuery.ajax({
                            type:"post",
                            url:location,
                            data: data,
                            success:function(data){
                                 window.location.href = checkout;
                            }
                      });
                 }
             </script>
```

Here store all the data in `var data = jQuery('#product_addtocart_form').serialize();`